# How to remove readonly attribute on (dblclick) in angular 6

Tags: typescript, attributes, angular6

I am new to angular 6 and I have a input with attribute `readonly` In which i want to remove `readonly` attribute when user double clicks the input.
But i was not be able to achieve that.
How to make it?
Thanks for any help!

html

```
<input type="text" class="todoInput" [readonly]="isReadOnly" (dblclick)="update()" value="{{todo.text}}">
```

component

```
 private isReadOnly: boolean = true;
 private update(){
    return this.isReadOnly === false;
  }
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried. Note that in Angular, you generally make the presence of an attribute dependent on a property of your component.

Comment: I updated @HereticMonkey

Comment: `update()` is returning a `boolean` that is always false. Make that `this.isReadOnly = false;` if you want to just set it. Use `this.isReadOnly = !this.isReadOnly;` if you want to toggle between them.

Comment: @HereticMonkey So much thanks brother, i want toggle that worked just super fine for me.